# LocaleContextHolder returns only language-code without country-code

Tags: spring-boot, locale, java-11, setlocale, parallelstream

I am currently using LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() to get the locale.

But the issue is, sometimes it returns language-code without country-code.

For e.g. : sometimes **en_US**, and sometimes **en** only

What could be the possible reason ?

FYI : Running Environment is : Java11, spring5.3.9.

How can I make sure that the getLocale() method should return lang-code_country-code (en_US) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

#### Simplifying the problem statement

When using LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() within parallel stream then LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() giving different locale for child thread.
For e.g. for main thread **en_us** and for other threads **en**.

```
contacts.parallelStream().forEach(contact -> {
Locale locale =  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
//some work....
});
```

output threads

> nio-8080 : en_US,
> onPool-worker : en,
> ......,
> onPool-worker : en

Comment: It returns what the user has set, so if that is only a language without a country it will return just that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, has LocaleContextHolder being set up somewhere ? or How can I know what the user has set as locale ?

Comment: What is set as al ocale is transfered to the `LocaleContextHolder`. For this a `LocaleResolver` is used.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, currently I am using Locale.US as default one.
But sometimes It returns en_US and sometimes en only